# adding 'use_frameworks!' in podfile is breaking app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

My iOS app contains both objective-C and Swift code. Now i have added **use_frameworks!**  at the top of pod file to use some swift library. Unfortunately it started giving compilation errors.

My pod version : 0.39.0

It started complaining about imports in bridge.h file

Pod file contains objective-C libraries. Now i want to add swift libraries.

How can i fix this issue. Let me know if needs more details

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'

xcodeproj 'Test.xcodeproj'

def devDependecies

    pod 'SocketRocket'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'MRProgress'
    pod 'GRMustache', '~> 7.3.0' 
    pod 'Realm', '=0.96.2'
    pod 'ADALiOS'
    pod 'Office365/Outlook'
    pod 'Office365/Discovery'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    #https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/160
    pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git=>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'
    pod 'iOSCalendarEventParser', '=0.0.4'
    pod 'OneDriveSDK'

end


target 'Test' do
    devDependecies
end
```

Sample error in bridge.h file : 
[image]

But this file exists under pod directory.
[image]

Comment: What kind of errors ?

Comment: workaround solution is adding as submodule...
Refer : http://michiganlabs.com/swift-library-objectivec-project/#.VvDaJhJ95mA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment Xcode does not allow that. use_frameworks works only with swift pods or libraries. If you add an objective C library you need to use the bridging header, therefore you need to remove the use_frameworks instruction  in order to make it work. The only work around I found is to only import through pods the objective C libraries and the swift libraries you can add them manually. You can copy the classes names and content and use them as if you would have created them.

Comment: Alex, what do u mean by adding them manually? How do you do that?

Comment: For objective C libraries just the pods file. For swift libraries as for example the alamofire project (library) or others like Haneke you add them manually. Download the library, then drag the project (blue icon) into xcode right below your main project. Afterwards go to your project and click on targets. Select your main App and  then go to general options.  Under Embedded Binaries click on the + icon and under Product select the library you have just dragged. That's it. Now you can import that library in whatever class you use, e.g  import Alamofire

Answer (score 1):

'youtube-ios-player-helper' can compile as a framework.
So remove it from the bridge header and just add an import line in your Swift classes

```
import youtube-ios-player-helper
```

Do the same for all pods that can compile as a framework